# How to Access twitter from Salesforce

Tags: twitter, salesforce

I am struggling to get this done, I need to connect to twitter rest Api 1.1 to get user details, time line etc.

What I came across is:

1. I have a Twitter App with access token ,secrete etc.

Now how to use all that access token etc to send (GET or POST) request to Twitter from Salesforce. How to set header or how to authenticate request. 
A tutorial would be very help full all I could find was tutorials for php etc I need it for **"salesforce"**

Note: I don't want to use a external lib

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this directly from Apex using the [HTTP REST library](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm). Here is the [first Google result](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Salesforce-Integration-With-Facbook-amp-Twitter/td-p/374877) for ["salesforce apex twitter integration"](https://www.google.com/search?q=salesforce+apex+twitter+integration&aq=0&oq=salesforce+apex+twitter&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.10508&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with this sample code from [Navatar_DbSup](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/68695):

```
VF CODE:
<apex:inputTextarea id="tweetInput" onkeyup="return maxLength();" onKeyPress="return maxLength();" value="{!newTweet}" rows="2" cols="73"/>
<apex:commandButton id="tweetBtn" style="height:35px;" value="Tweet" action="{!postTweet}" />
Controller code:
*** post tweets into twitter*/
public String newTweet{get;set;}
public Void postTweet()
{
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
Method = 'POST';
req.setMethod(Method);
req.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml');
newTweet = newTweet.replace('%','%25').replace('&','%26').replace('@','%40').replace(';','%3B').replace('?','%3F').replace('/','%2F').replace(':','%3A').replace('#','%23').replace('=','%3D').replace('+','%2B').replace('$','%24').replace(',','%2C').replace(' ','%20').replace('<','%3C').replace('>','%3E').replace('{','%7B').replace('}','%7D').replace('[','%5B').replace(']','%5D').replace('`','%60').replace('|','%7C').replace('\\','%5C').replace('^','%5E').replace('"','%22').replace('\'','%27').replace('!','%21').replace('*','%2A').replace('(','%28').replace(')','%29').replace('~','%7F');
req.setBody('status='+newTweet);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

OAuth oa = new OAuth();
if(!oa.setService())
{
message=oa.message;
}
oa.sign(req);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
system.debug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&7' + res.getBody());
PostTweetbody = res.getBody() + '___' + message;
newTweet = '';
}
```